# Update notifier automatically re-enabled after updates?

Tags: updates, update-notifier

I had disabled the GUI update notifier by selecting Preferences -> Software Updater -> Settings:
Check for new updates: Never.
Instead I wanted my apt-systemd-daily to do everything in combination with unattended-upgrades.
It worked fine.

But today I see my setting "Never" has been replaced by "Daily". How come?
Has any of my upgrades done this?

In this case, I would have to reset it again and again. Right?

Thanks
bpn

Comment: If you edit the files in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d (like you would to configure unattended Upgrades), those changes will show in the Update Manager GUI. They all share the same config files. Which also means that if you select "Check for New Update: Never", then Unattended Upgrades will obey that setting and never check.

Comment: OK. But this means I cannot automate my upgrades and at the same time tell the GUI update notifier not to bother me anymore?